# Laravel configuration whit variable function

Tags: php, laravel

i have file in app/config called rules.php

well, i need use a variable function like this:

```
return array(
    'a' => 'a',
    'b' => function (){
        return ....someting....;
    },
)
```

how i perform this action?

in this way not work, the result of:

```
Config::get('rules.b')
```

is: The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow what the error says.
Try with :

```
return (object) array(
'a' => 'a',
'b' => function (){
    return ....someting....;
},
```

)